# Implementing model inheritance on springboot have strange data repository behavior

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I'm going to create a model that implement inheritance concept. I was thinking that it is possible by creating two (or more) tables (one for the parent class and the other for the child class), then create two (or more) model based on the table.

I currently created a model that acts as a parent class, and made it abstract

```
@NoArgsConstructor // lombok
@AllArgsConstructor // lombok
@Data // lombok
@Entity(name="Account")
@Inheritance
public abstract class AccountModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    // Some other fields and getters and setters here
}
```

and then created child class that extends above class

```
@NoArgsConstructor // lombok
@Data // lombok
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true) // lombok
@Entity(name="Administrator")
public class AdministratorModel extends AccountModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    // some other fields and getters and setters here
}
```

(currently, the username is used as the join)

and I created two repositories for both models

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountModel, String>{};

@Repository
public interface AdministratorRepository extends JpaRepository<AdministratorModel, String>{};
```

Then, I tested it by trying to save new `AdministratorModel` object to `AdministratorRepository` by using `JpaRepository.save()` method.

I was expecting that this setting will fill data from the object to both of the tables on the database, and automatically mapped all properties to each table. but, the data is only saved as one record on the parent table, and adding new column (one column is something that may refer to child table, and other column is properties of the child table, without adding the join column 'username'), while leaving the child table empty.

I think that I'm doing it wrong.
Then, how to make it works as expected ?
Should I not used inheritance and save the model manually using two (or more) repositories, or should I only create one repository with a custom query, or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of inheritance should add non default strategy to `@Inheritance` annotation.

Changing `@Inheritance` to `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` fixes the problem.

As the documentation says this strategy is:

> A strategy in which fields that are specific to a 
>       subclass are mapped to a separate table than the fields 
>       that are common to the parent class, and a join is 
>       performed to instantiate the subclass.

Comment: answering my own question